# Moai SDK AKU not existing

Tags: frameworks, moai

In the book [Developing Mobile Games with Moai SDK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782165061) is referred to the AKU, the interface between host and framework. Also in [some of the code](https://github.com/moai/moai-dev/blob/master/distribute/hosts/src/GlutHost.cpp#L7) AKU is included.

But no AKU files can be found in the source code at all. Is this a part that is currently worked on or has been deprecated in the development branch? Unfortunately the release versions can't be downloaded anymore because they still [link to the shut down moai cloud](http://getmoai.com/sdk/moai-sdk-download.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the book was released, Moai SDK suffered a major reorganization to be a little bit more modular.

All the AKU stuff was moved to "host.cpp" files across modules. For example in moai-core, you'll find a [host.cpp](https://github.com/moai/moai-dev/blob/development/src/moai-core/host.cpp) file that includes several AKU methods.

Besides this, you can also clone the [Version-1.4p0 tag](https://github.com/moai/moai-dev/tree/Version-1.4p0/), that is the one I've used for the book.

Hope this works for you!